# Manipulating lines of data

Tags: c#, database, text-files

I have millions of lines generated from data updated every second which look like this:

```
104500 4783
104501 8930
104502 21794
104503 21927
104505 5746
104506 9968
104509 5867
104510 46353
104511 7767
104512 4903
```

The column on the left represents time (hhmmss format), and the column on the right is data which is updated second-by-second.  As you can see however, it isn't actually second-by-second, and there are some missing times (10:45:04, 10:45:07, 10:45:08 are missing in this example).  My goal is to add in the missing seconds, and to use the data from the previous second for that missing second, like this:

```
104500 4783
104501 8930
104502 21794
104503 21927
104504 21927 --
104505 5746
104506 9968
104507 9968 --
104508 9968 --
104509 5867
104510 46353
104511 7767
104512 4903
```

I don't want the "--" in the result, I just put those there to mark the added lines.  So far I've tried to accomplish this using StreamReader and StreamWriter, but it doesn't seem like they're going to get me what I want.  I'm a newbie programmer and a newbie to C#, so if you could just point me in the right direction, that would be great.  I'm really just wondering if this is even possible to do in C#...I've spent a lot of time on MSDN and here on SO looking for a solution to this, but so far haven't found any.

Edit: The lines are in a text file, and I want to store the newly created data in a new text file.

Comment: I assume the lines are from a text file and you want to create a new one with the missing values?

Comment: +1 for a great (well written, explained and formatted) first question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have included that in my question.  The lines are in a text file, and I want to store the newly created data in a new text file.

Comment: Can you post the code that is outputting this data?

Comment: I get the data through a program like this: I run the program, and while the program is running, these lines of data are generated in a text file each second (or almost each second).  If no data comes in for that second, a line for that second isn't written to the text file.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that outputs this data.

Comment: Good question, but in future, please don't add " (C#)" to the end of your title. That's what we use tags for here at [so].

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave it out next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, here is the whole shooting match, tested and working against your test data:

```
public void InjectMissingData()
{
    DataLine lastDataLine = null;
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create("c:\\temp\\out.txt")))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\in.txt"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var dataLine = DataLine.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

                while (lastDataLine != null && dataLine.Occurence - lastDataLine.Occurence > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                {
                    lastDataLine = new DataLine(lastDataLine.Occurence + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), lastDataLine.Data);
                    writer.WriteLine(lastDataLine.Line);
                }

                writer.WriteLine(dataLine.Line);

                lastDataLine = dataLine;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DataLine
{
    public static DataLine Parse(string line)
    {
        var timeString = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", line.Substring(0, 2), line.Substring(2, 2),
                                       line.Substring(4, 2));

        return new DataLine(TimeSpan.Parse(timeString), long.Parse(line.Substring(7, line.Length - 7).Trim()));
    } 

    public DataLine(TimeSpan occurence, long data)
    {
        Occurence = occurence;
        Data = data;
    }

    public TimeSpan Occurence { get; private set; }
    public long Data { get; private set; }

    public string Line
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}{1}{2} {3}", 
            Occurence.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, Char.Parse("0")), 
            Occurence.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, Char.Parse("0")), 
            Occurence.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, Char.Parse("0")),
            Data); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a rather simple question my first thought is that this is some kind of homework or job interview question--not necessarily but it's worth considering before posting a full-source-code answer to an easy problem.

Comment: Hey Bill K, it had occurred to me, but it was well written and polite so for me it's quite simple; people post questions, if you want to answer it, do so, if you want to down vote it, question it, poke fun at it or even ignore it, you can do all of those things.  You can also complain when someone else answers it.  Freedom, you gotta love it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree--Hence my just gently reminding people that providing code-complete answers to simple questions you may be doing nobody but yourself a favor.

Comment: Bill K, you really are a bright spark, that is exactly why I did it, I wanted the buzz of a few more points.  One day I might aspire to answering only the questions worthy of a great intellect.  Until then I will toil away with the proletariat picking up points where I can.

Comment: I have no way to prove it, but this isn't for a job or a homework assignment, it's just for personal use.  Thanks again Myles.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I agree, but Bill K does have a point, there are some real blatent abuses of SO.  They normally get closed very quickly.  I thought this was worthy of a response so it was my call to spend time on it.

Comment: Hmm, strange that you feel that I meant for points--do you feel that's all you get out of posting?  I meant because you get to write the code/solve the problem and that you are probably harming anyone who didn't get the opportunity to work through it themselves aided by insightful hints (Like with George's answer)...  It's harder that way but better for everyone else.

Comment: Why is that strange Bill? Are you trying to tell us you don't like having points? I think you love your points, I think you cuddle you points to sleep. I agree with you though, George's answer is much better than mine, for exactly the reasons you state.  I'm just laughing at how bothered you are! No, points aren;t my only reason to post.  I like puzzles, I like programming computers and I like helping poeple.  The points are nice little feel good bonus.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you need to put together.

1. Read a file line-by-line: See here: [Reading a Text File One Line at a Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. Writing a file line-by-line : [`StreamWriter.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx)
3. Keep track of the last read line. (Just use a variable in your while loop where you read the lines)
4. Check whether there is a gap. Maybe by parsing the first column ([`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)) using [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783872.aspx). If there is a gap then write the last read line, incrementing the timespan.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have a grasp on 1-3, but #4 is totally new to me so I'll start reading about string.Split and TimeSpan.Parse.

Answer (score 3):

In adition to all answers, considering that you are talking about a huge files, consider use of  [MemoryMappedFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx), can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to see how to use them from C#.

This is *not performance* improvement, but *memory improvement* definetely is.

Answer (score 1):

So far as inserting new entries between certain ones goes, I would advise reading in the text file into separated lines, and then storing them in a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). That way, you can use the [`Insert(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method to insert your new lines. From there, you can write the lines back into the file.

When reading the lines, you can use either of the static helper methods in the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh.aspx) class: [`ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) and [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c4w9x9x.aspx).

Note: I've added links to the MSDN Documentation for each of the methods and classes I've mentioned, since you said you are new to C# and programming in general.

Comment: There are millions of lines, not sure storing the whole file in memory is a good idea.

Comment: If he is reading millions of lines that might get a little unweildy, especially since to find a missing line he just needs two lines in memory at a time - Current and Previous.

Comment: Both comments are true - this is just an suggestion. Any actual solution would be dependent entirely on the implementation. Either way, the answer should lead him to find a solution that suits him.

Answer (score 1):

```
String prevTime;
String prevData;

while(String line = myStreamReader.ReadLine())
{
    String[] parts = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
    String time = parts[0];
    String data = parts[1];

    Int32 iPrevTime = Int32.Parse(prevTime);
    Int32 iCurrentTime = Int32.Parse(time);

    // May need to loop here if you're missing more than one second
    if(iCurrentTime > iPrevTime + 1)   
          AddData((iPrevTime + 1).ToString(), prevData);

    AddData(time, data);
    prevTime = time;
    prevData = data;
}
```

Here is some pseudo-code to get you started.  I think you will want this type of algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for writing this, I'll read about what it does and see if it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the times are never more than a second apart. If that assumption is wrong, it's easy enough to modify the below so it writes the lastValue in a loop for each second missing.
*Update* I missed in your example that it can in fact miss multiple seconds. I changed the example below to address that.

```
using (StreamReader reader = OpenYourInputFile())
using (StreamWriter writer = OpenYourOutputFile())
{
   TimeSpan? lastTime;
   TimeSpan currentTime, maxDiff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
   string lastValue, currentline, currentValue, format = "{0:hhmmss} {1}";

   while( (currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      string[] s = currentLine.Split(' ');
      currentTime = DateTime.ParseExact("hhmmss", s[0] CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
      currentValue = s[1];

      if (lastTime.HasValue && currentTime - lastTime.Value > maxDiff) 
      { 
        for(int x = 1; x <= (currentTime - lastTime).Seconds; x++) writer.WriteLine(string.Format(format, DateTime.Today.Add(lastTime).AddSeconds(x), lastValue);
      }

      writer.WriteLine(string.Format(format, DateTime.Today.Add(currentTime), currentValue);

      lastTime = currentTime;
      lastValue = currentValue;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'll read about what this does and then try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some rough code for you. I'm not properly disposing everything, it's just to get you started.

```
        DateTime lastTime;
        string lastValue = null;
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("path");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("newPath"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] lineData = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Parse(lineData[0]);
            string value = lineData[1];

            if (lastValue != null)
            {
                while (lastTime < currentTime.AddSeconds(-1))
                {
                    lastTime = lastTime.AddSeconds(1);
                    writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lastTime, lastValue);
                }
            }
            writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", currentTime, value);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            lastValue = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string line;//The line that is read.
        string previousLine = "0 0";
        int prevTime = 0;

        //These "using"'s are so that the resources they use will be freed when the block ( i.e. {} ) is finished.
        using (System.IO.StreamReader originalFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\users\\Me\\t.txt"))
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter newFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\users\\Me\\t2.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = originalFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //"Split" changes the words in "line" (- that are separated by a space) to an array. 
                //"Parse" takes the first in that array (by using "[0]") and changes it into an integer.
                int time = int.Parse(line.Split(' ')[0]);
                while (prevTime != 0 && time > ++prevTime) newFile.WriteLine(prevTime.ToString() + " " + previousLine.Split(' ')[1]);

                previousLine = line;
                prevTime = time;
                newFile.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```